# How to add a class to classpath to not get import errors in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath

I am trying to compile a Java class. I am getting 'error: cannot find symbol'.

```
HealthCheckServletTest.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.epoc.base.HealthCheckServlet;
                    ^
  symbol:   class HealthCheckServlet
  location: package com.epoc.base
```

The code for the Test class is

```
package com.epoc.base;

import com.epoc.base.HealthCheckServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class HealthCheckServletTest {

    public void testServlet() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);
        new HealthCheckServlet().doGet(request,response);

        assertEquals("text/html", response.getContentType());
    }
}
```

My javac command contains the required .class file. It also has all other required dependencies.

```
javac HealthCheckServletTest.java -classpath /tmp/taxserver/WEB-INF/classes/com/epoc/base/HealthCheckServlet.class:.........
```

Why am I getting a import not found error even though the .class file is present in the classpath ?